# How to change a field name in JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, jquery-ui, jackson

I'm using jackson to convert an object of mine to json.
The object has 2 fields:

```
@Entity
public class City {
   @id
   Long id;
   String name;
   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
   public Long getId() { return id; }
   public void setName(Long id){ this.id = id; }
}
```

Since I want to use this with the jQuery auto complete feature I want 'id' to appear as 'value' in the json and 'name' to appear as 'label'. The documentation of jackson is not clear on this and I've tried every annotation that even remotely seems like it does what I need but I can't get `name` to appear as `label` and `id` to appear as `value` in the json.

Does anyone know how to do this or if this is possible?

Comment: if If you were ever going to potentially use the entity ("City") for any other purpose or business logic, I'd avoid defining its JSON representation as Label & Value. OTOH if this is purely reference data used for combos, you're likely going to have more -- making a generic entity (Pair or Option) to cover all of these is a possible approach to consider.

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Have you tried using @JsonProperty?

```
@Entity
public class City {
   @id
   Long id;
   String name;

   @JsonProperty("label")
   public String getName() { return name; }

   public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }

   @JsonProperty("value")
   public Long getId() { return id; }

   public void setId(Long id){ this.id = id; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that, however I was doing `@JsonProperty(value="label")` and it was not working, I've tried it as you have suggested and it works! thanks man this will really help simplify the code now.

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Just that I'm using Jackson with RESTEasy and this doesn't work :-/ Strange!

Comment: verify that Jackson really is the configured provider and not something else

Comment: is there a way to leverage Jackson (or GSON) to change a property name in an already-existing JSON string (not during serialization)?

Comment: I have used object         @JsonProperty("object")
        val jsonObject: String, ...but failed

Answer (score 58):

Be aware that there is `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty` in Jackson 1.x and `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty` in Jackson 2.x. Check which ObjectMapper you are using (from which version), and make sure you use the proper annotation.

Comment: There is also a `org.json4s.jackson` namespace. :) and possibly other implementation of `jackson` YMMV.

Answer (score 32):

### Jackson

If you are using Jackson, then you can use the [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation to customize the name of a given JSON property.

Therefore, you just have to annotate the entity fields with the `@JsonProperty` annotation and provide a custom JSON property name, like this:

```
@Entity
public class City {

   @Id
   @JsonProperty("value")
   private Long id;

   @JsonProperty("label")
   private String name;

   //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

### JavaEE or JakartaEE JSON-B

JSON-B is the standard binding layer for converting Java objects to and from JSON. If you are using JSON-B, then you can override the JSON property name via the [`@JsonbProperty`](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/users-guide.html) annotation:

```
@Entity
public class City {

   @Id
   @JsonbProperty("value")
   private Long id;

   @JsonbProperty("label")
   private String name;

   //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 22):

There is one more option to rename field:

[Jackson MixIns](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Useful if you deal with third party classes, which you are **not able to annotate**, or you just do not want to pollute the class with Jackson specific annotations.

The Jackson documentation for Mixins is outdated, so this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-mixin-to-the-rescue) can provide more clarity. In essence: you create mixin class which does the serialization in the way you want. Then register it to the ObjectMapper:

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(ThirdParty.class, MyMixIn.class);
```

Comment: I am curious will this affect the performance when serializing/deserializing fields?