# How to change wrapper name in jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Right now the json gets serialized like so:

```
{ MyClassList : [{
  {
   ...
  },

  {
   ...
  },
}]
```

class:

```
public MyClass{
  properties here ...
}
```

java object being serialized:

```
new ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
list.add(new MyClass());
```

How do I change "MyClassList" to another custom name? for example, how do I change it to "MyClassAbc"?

Comment: How do you serialize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/change-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)

You can use @JsonProperty("MyClassAbc")

So you can rename the "RootName"

```
class MyInterfaceList{
      @JsonProperty("MyClassAbc")
      private List<MyClass> list;

      public List<MyClass> getList(){
          return list;
      }
      public void setList(List<MyClass> list){
          this.list =list;
      }
   }
```

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer as I think there is no other way. thanks.