# Overriding JSON Response in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'd like to serialize, via Jackson, my `Foo` interface:

```
public interface Foo { }
```

It has two instances: Standard and Debug responses. I'll only show the `Standard` response as it adequately conveys my question.

```
public class FooRegular implements Foo {

     private int number;

     public FooRegular(final int number) { this.number = number; }

     @JsonProperty("NUM")
     public getNumber() { 
       return number;
     }  
}
```

Note that, I'm returning a `Foo` in my Controller class:

```
public Response sendResponse() {
  Foo foo = getFoo(); // returns FooRegular
  return buildResponse(foo); // returns some Response with `foo` as its body
}
```

However, my response is:

`{ number : 1234 }`

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7272468/409976), which is what I've tried, but I'm not seeing the expected result.

How can I override the JSON response to have a key of `NUM` rather than `number`?

Comment: I've tried a small test case with your classes and `@JsonProperty` as you have it works fine. What does your `buildResponse` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your `FooRegular` class with an `ObjectMapper` and your `JsonProperty` annotation is working fine. Without knowing what your `buildResponse` method looks like, I can only assume the problem is in there.

You could try one of these for your resource method:

```
public Foo sendResponse() {
    return getFoo();
}
```

or

```
public Response sendResponse() {
    Foo foo = getFoo();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String foostr = mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(foo);
    return Response.ok().entity(foostr).build();
}
```