# Change key name in bean to JSON conversion dynamically

Tags: java, json, struts2

I have a entity bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name="info")
public class Info{    

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

I am using this bean with hibernate to store the object value in database.
However I have a requirement to convert the bean as JSON like this

```
{
  "param1":"AB_9999"
}
```

instead of

```
{
   "name":"AB_9999"
}
```

I don't want to change the column name but also want the JSON should have **'param1'** instead of **'name'** as key.

I can already convert the bean to JSON only thing I wish to know is,

**How to change the key name dynamically** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change field name in JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/change-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)

Comment: What library did you use to convert to JSON?

Comment: Oh, this edit changes everything. :D Why don't you accept @YasserZamani answer? Or comment if it is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="info")
public class Info{    

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @JSON(name="param1") //I added this
    public String getName(){return name;}

}
```