# Java Jackson use different property name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a generated Java Class which is annotated with `@XMLElement` on the fields to change the name from upper to lower case:

```
class RECTYPE {
    @XmlElement(name = "simple")
    public String SIMPLE;    

    @XmlElement(name = "bool")
    public Boolean BOOL;
}
```

I know I could use `@JsonProperty` ([Change field name in JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/change-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)) to get lower case Json but I don't want to change my generated class.

Can I somehow use the `name` property of the `@XMLElement` Annotation that I have and tell Jackson to use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Mix-in annotations on an other class. This migth be useful in your case, the Mix-in class would look like this :

```
abstract class RectypeMixIn {

  @JsonProperty("simple") abstract String getSimple(); // rename property
  @JsonProperty("bool") abstract Boolean getBool(); // rename property  
}
```

And cofigure your ObjectMapper this way :

```
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(RECTYPE.class, RectypeMixIn.class);
```

Check this the doc [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) for more details

Comment: Thanks! That would also be a way but I would have to generate way more Classes. With the other solution I can use basically one line of code to use the already existing annotation! But it might be useful for someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jaudo - the question was already answered here: [Change field name in JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/change-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)

I used the following snipped to use the `@XMLElement` annotations:

`objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.pair( new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance()), new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector()));`