# Spring: bind url query param to POJO

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have request like ...?abc=value and following rest implementation (Spring):

```
@GetMapping("/")
String getSth(Pojo pojo) {
...
}
```

where *Pojo* is

```
Pojo {
 private String someOtherName;
 //getters, setters
}
```

Is it possible to bind query param *abc* to class attribute *someOtherName*? I know, that if query param fits to pojo attribute, it works by default...
Does Spring support custom mappings between POJO attributes and query params?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change field name in JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/change-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)

Comment: Not without providing your own data binder.

Comment: try `@JsonProperty("abc") private String someOtherName;`