# JsonProperty not changing the field name

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

i tried to change a field name as shown below :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Resource {
@JsonProperty("serviceMetaData")
    private List<String> metadata;
}
```

but response still showing metadata field. please help .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/change-field-name-in-json-using-jackson this question will help you to figure it out

Comment: Checkout imports are correct: [org.codehaus.jackson versus com.fasterxml.jackson.core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782706/org-codehaus-jackson-versus-com-fasterxml-jackson-core)