# Spring Boot: Problems deserializing JSON objects. Change property names

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm developing a back-end web application using Spring Boot with Java and I have the following problem:
A REST service returns me the following JSON:

```
{
   "cap":"98888"
}
```

This is my JAVA class which models the output based on the content:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyObject {

    private String cap;
    
}
```

I would like to change the field name for MY service to return the following JSON:

```
{
   "CAP":"98888"
}
```

In my JAVA code, I make the call via RestTemplate, like this:

```
return restTemplate.postForObject(uriBuilder.build().toUri(), new HttpEntity<>(request, headers), MyObject.class);
```

I've tried to use tons of stuff with Jackson, including `@JsonProperty`, like this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("CAP")
    private String cap;
    
}
```

But the result is this:

```
{
   "CAP":null
}
```

As if it no longer matches the original name of the property. In practice I can only get an output with correct value but original field name (WHICH I DON'T WANT) or an output with the name of the field I want (i.e. CAP) but with a `null` value.
Which is the right way to rename properties with Spring annotations?

Comment: check this out [How to change a field name in JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/how-to-change-a-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)

Comment: This approach should work.