# Java Jackson - Change class name during serialization

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a class like below. When I serialize using Jackson library, I want the 'StudentClass' object name in the Json as 'class' and not 'studentClass'. I tried few things but did not work out. Please see below

```
public class Classification {
    private Department department;
    private StudentClass studentClass;

// getters and setters
}

public class Department {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
// getters and setters
}

public class StudentClass {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
// getters and setters
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "classification": {
        "department": {
            "id": 123,
            "title": "Healthcare"
        },
        "class": {
            "id": 456,
            "title": "blah"
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual output:**

```
{
    "classification": {
        "department": {
            "id": 123,
            "title": "Healthcare"
        },
        "studentClass": {
            "id": 456,
            "title": "blah"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding below config on StudentClass, however, it yielded me a different result as below

```
@JsonTypeName("class")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
public class StudentClass {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
// getters and setters
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "classification": {
        "department": {
            "id": 123,
            "title": "Healthcare"
        },
        "studentClass": {
            "class": {
                "id": 456,
                "title": "blah"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a field name in JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/how-to-change-a-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)

Answer (score 1):

Well I had to just put @JsonProperty("class") like below and it worked. My bad, I was running behind adding a different config.

```
public class Classification {
    private Department department;
    @JsonProperty("class")
    private StudentClass studentClass;

// getters and setters
}
```